# Javascript this scoping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made two dropdowns, but each selection affects the other

`var dd = new DropDown( $('.f-box') );`

I have scoped them to `this` yet it is not identifing the unique element but affects all matching options.

```
   DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);

            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);

        });
    }
}
```

It looks likes    `obj.opts.on('click',function(){}` is matching all `.f-box` elements instead of the one that is currently being clicked on. Is the way i'm assigning it to `$(this)` incorrect?

http://jsfiddle.net/42dbqugj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing all `.f-box` elements to the `Dropdown()` function, hence it operates on all of them.

The quick way to solve this is to loop through `.f-box` and call the function on them individually:

```
$('.f-box').each(function() {
  new DropDown($(this));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/42dbqugj/1/)

However, a better approach entirely would be to change this logic to a jQuery plugin. Then the standard pattern is to work on each element individually.

Comment: That's what I figured, in this case passing in a unique ID to ` new Dropdown('#id')` would also work.

Comment: "*change this logic to a jQuery plugin. Then [it will] work on each element individually*" - not necessarily. Sure, the standard pattern for jQuery plugins is that they use `.each` just like you have shown, but it works on individual elements because of this `.each` not because it's a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @bergi I agree. The answer does say standard pattern too :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I got it, but maybe the wording should be improved so that one doesn't misinterpret it.